# Is it possible to cultivate Sharingans?

Tags: naruto

I got into a discussion with this with my brother the other day and I was wondering if this would be a valid way to cultivate and stock up on Sharingans.

We see that Madara/Tobi had an entire laboratory of Sharingans, presumably gathered from the corpses from the Uchiha Massacre. Now, if someone like Kabuto were to reanimate Uchiha, they would be revived back with their own eyes as we saw with Itachi.

Then, would it be possible to remove the reanimated Itachi's eyes and store them for use for a later date? My brother told me that the problem with this theory is that a reanimated body using Kabuto's Endo Tensei would just have body parts that would turn to paper/dust if detached from its body, as we saw from many reanimations who lost their limbs in the war.

But what if Kabuto un-did the Endo Tensei jutsu immediately proceeding taking out the eyes of Itachi. Would the eyes still turn to paper/dust or would they manifest in a physical form? If so, this would allow someone like Kabuto to infinitely cultivate Sharingans by continuously reanimating and un-reanimating an Uchiha, something that could be very powerful when comboed with Izanagi.

If the above is not possible with Kabuto's jutsu, how about with Orochimaru's Endo Tensei - the one he used to revive the First and Second Hogake against the Third Hokage in the first Naruto series? If I recall, Orochimaru's original Endo Tensei didn't make the bodies immortal or turn to paper.

Comment: It turned into paper and there we saw that the bodies used by Orochimaru was that of the Sound ninja.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short not possible. 
When madara was called by endo tensei he had his sharingan, even he showed the five kages the power of rinnegan . When he was brought back to alive by Obito, he was blind as his original eyes were given to Pain. This proves that you can't simply use endo tensei to manipulate body parts. Releasing a person from endo tensei simply means he/she is free to move on their own will, just like madara when he managed to release himself from kabuto's control.